# Howto get the right sha1 value, that is recoginsed by haveibeenpawned?

Tags: hash, passwords, sha1

i want to check my passwords with help of the sha1-hashed pw files from haveibeenpawned. And of course I want to do it locally ;-). In order to be able to compare those hashes with a sha1-hash, that i created from a password, I used two different approaches:

php:

```
  $pw='1234';
  $pwhash = strtoupper(sha1($pw));
```

c:

```
  char pw[] = "1234";
  size_t pwlen = sizeof(pw);
  SHA1(pw, pwlen, pwhash); 
  // and convert binary to Hex-string "02X" ...
```

First question is: Why the hashes are different? Is there a hidden salt?
And why the won't match with the hashes of Troy Hunt?

[Update] Meanwhile the php hash is matched in the list. I didn't limit the string to 40 chars and had "\r" and "\n" in it.

Answer (score 1):

You're computing the SHA1 hashes of two different chunks of data.

In your PHP code:

```
$pw='1234';
$pwhash = strtoupper(sha1($pw));
```

you are, I presume, computing the hash of a 4-byte sequence (I don't know PHP very well). The result should be `7110eda4d09e062aa5e4a390b0a572ac0d2c0220`.

In your C code (which is incomplete, BTW; where does this `SHA` function come from?):

```
char pw[] = "1234";
size_t pwlen = sizeof(pw);
SHA1(pw, pwlen, pwhash);
```

`pwlen` is 5, not 4, because applying `sizeof` to a string literal gives you the length of the string *plus 1* for the terminating `'\0'` character. You're computing the SHA1 sum of the sequence `{'1', '2', '3', '4', '\0'}`, which should be `8bef71a3d039e425fe43872cc178441c206b3fda`.

Try this:

```
char pw[] = "1234";
SHA1(pw, strlen(pw), pwhash);
```

In your C code (which is incomplete, BTW; where does this `SHA` function come from?):

```
char pw[] = "1234";
size_t pwlen = sizeof(pw);
SHA1(pw, pwlen, pwhash);
```

`pwlen` is 5, not 4, because applying `sizeof` to a string literal gives you the length of the string *plus 1* for the terminating `'\0'` character. You're computing the SHA1 sum of the sequence `{'1', '2', '3', '4', '\0'}`, which should be `8bef71a3d039e425fe43872cc178441c206b3fda`.

Try this:

```
char pw[] = "1234";
SHA1(pw, strlen(pw), pwhash);
```

A simpler way to get the SHA1 checksum of a given password, if you're on a Unix-like system or have an `sha1sum1` command installed, is:

```
echo -n 'your_password' | sha1sum
```

If you want to remove the '  -' at the end of the output line, you can pipe the output through sed;

```
echo -n 'your password' | sha1sum | sed 's/ .*//'
```

Comment: perfect answer, Keith. Yes, this helped a lot! Now, both versions are running fine :-).

Comment: Something, that I did not understand: You and I, we see that there are different hashes for php and c. That means, you are right, but I don't understand, why these are different chunks?

aah, and sha1() ...

this is resolved by
    #include <openssl/sha.h>

Comment: The definition of the SHA1 hash function is language-independent. The results differ because your PHP code was computing the checksum of the 4-byte sequence `{'1', '2', '3', '4'}`, and the C code was computing the checksum of the 5-byte sequence `{'1', '2', '3', '4', '\0'}`. Was that not clear from my answer?

Comment: Oh man Keith, don't worry. You did the utmost! I didn't catch the idea, that '0' will be part of the hash. Thanx again for Your detailed informations! All my questions are answered perfectly :-)